# ASP.NET VB add button that has removechild() function

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, replace, removechild

I just want to know how to add a button that has a removechild() or replacechild() function on my XML. Been searching for this for a week now.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

This is my xml file content

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <theNews>
 <news>
 <contents>News3 Contents</contents>
 <title>News3 Title</title>
 <pubDate>February 13, 2012</pubDate>
 </news>
 <news>
 <contents>News2 Contents</contents>
 <title>News2 Title</title>
 <pubDate>February 1, 2012</pubDate>
 </news>
 <news>
 <contents>News1 Contents</contents>
 <title>News1 Title</title>
 <pubDate>January 22, 2012</pubDate>
 </news>
 </theNews>
```

This is the code for my News Updater

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="NewsUpdater.aspx.vb" Inherits="NewsUpdater" %>

 <%-- Add content controls here --%><asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" 
contentplaceholderid="ContentPlaceHolder1">

        <p>
            &nbsp;</p>
        <table align="center" style="width: 63%">
            <tr>
                <td align=center>
                    <div>
    <h3>News Title</h3>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTitle" Width="308px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
    <h3>News Content</h3>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtContents" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="119px" Width="513px"></asp:TextBox>


                        <br />

                        <br />
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update News" />
</div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>
            <br />
        </p>
```

And this is the code behind the NewsUpdater button

```
 Partial Class NewsUpdater
 Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim xmlFile As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
    xmlFile.Load("D:\My Documents\PresentableII\NewsContent.xml")

    Dim theNewsTag As System.Xml.XmlElement = xmlFile.CreateElement("news")
    Dim theTitleTag As System.Xml.XmlElement = xmlFile.CreateElement("title")
    Dim theContentsTag As System.Xml.XmlElement = xmlFile.CreateElement("contents")

    Dim theTitleText As System.Xml.XmlText = xmlFile.CreateTextNode(txtTitle.Text)
    Dim theContentsText As System.Xml.XmlText = xmlFile.CreateTextNode(txtContents.Text)

    theTitleTag.PrependChild(theTitleText)
    theContentsTag.PrependChild(theContentsText)


    theNewsTag.PrependChild(theTitleTag)
    theNewsTag.PrependChild(theContentsTag)

    xmlFile.DocumentElement.PrependChild(theNewsTag)
    xmlFile.Save("D:\My Documents\PresentableII\NewsContent.xml")

    Response.Redirect("NewsFrame.aspx")

End Sub
```

I want to add another button that has a function of remove or replace the last/latest entry to the xml.

Comment: Where is the XML - server side or client side? If client side, is using jQuery ok?

Comment: I've already updated my post. please check it out. I'm on the server side

Comment: Thanks. how do you define "last/latest entry"? e.g. is it the last child of the root node?

Comment: yes. e.g. how can I remove or replace the lastchild that would be the News3 title&Content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So would this line do what you want?

```
xmlFile.DocumentElement.RemoveChild(xmlFile.DocumentElement.LastChild)
xmlFile.DocumentElement.AppendChild(your_replacement_element)
```

Comment: should I just copy and paste your code and add it on my code above? or do I need to modify it? do I need to add a button for this one?

sorry, for the questions. I'm new to this, you're guide would greatly help me with this one

Comment: No probs :) If you paste the above code into yours where you want to do the replacement - changing your_replacement_element with your own of course - that should be enough. If not I probably misunderstood - just let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot bukko! You've helped me lot. :)